# 'rxjs/operators' error angular 14 proje ( ng serve )

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am developing a project with angular 14. I am using angular material. I started getting the following errors. I started getting this error after what I did, I couldn't find it, can you help me?

```
./node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2020/core.mjs:31708:61-66 - Error: export 'share' (imported as 'share') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/forms/fesm2020/forms.mjs:1082:38-41 - Error: export 'map' (imported as 'map') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:630:36-45 - Error: export 'startWith' (imported as 'startWith') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:630:56-65 - Error: export 'switchMap' (imported as 'switchMap') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:635:38-42 - Error: export 'take' (imported as 'take') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:635:47-56 - Error: export 'switchMap' (imported as 'switchMap') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:757:82-88 - Error: export 'filter' (imported as 'filter') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:757:233-239 - Error: export 'filter' (imported as 'filter') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)

./node_modules/@angular/material/fesm2020/autocomplete.mjs:758:4-7 - Error: export 'map' (imported as 'map') was not found in 'rxjs/operators' (module has no exports)
```

---

```
    Node:16.20.0

        Package                         Version
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        @angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.12
        @angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.12
        @angular-devkit/core            14.2.12
        @angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.12
        @angular/cdk                    14.2.7
        @angular/cli                    14.2.12
        @angular/language-service       14.2.0
        @angular/material               14.2.7
        @schematics/angular             14.2.12
        rxjs                            7.5.7
        typescript                      4.7.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually i delete package-lock.json and node modules as well install node modules and it starts working
You can try this way